# whenever i am trying to post this error is showing "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) "

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am not sure why I am getting this error. Whenever I am trying to place an order on my ecommerce project website. I am getting this error.

```
:5000/api/order:1 
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

 code: "ERR_BAD_RESPONSE"
    config: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
    message: "Request failed with status code 500"
    name: "AxiosError"
    request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
    response:
    config: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
    data: {index: 0, code: 11000, keyPattern: {…}, keyValue: {…}}
    headers: {content-length: '123', content-type: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
    request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
    status: 500
    statusText: "Internal Server Error"
    [[Prototype]]: Object
    [[Prototype]]: Error
```

This is my useEffect request.

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const createOrder = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await userRequest.post('/order', {
                    username: currentUser.username,
                    products: cart?.products.map((item) => ({
                        productId: item._id,
                        quantity: item._quantity,
                    })),
                    amount: cart?.total,
                    address: "India",
                    pincode: "110046",
                    phone: "1234567890",
                    email: "johndoe@xyz.com",
                    shippingPrice: "120",
                    reference: orderNo,
                    paymentMethod: "Cash on delivery",
                    status: "pending"
                })
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
        createOrder()
    }, [cart, currentUser])
```

This is userRequest function.

```
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root"))?.user;
const currentUser = user && JSON.parse(user).currentUser;
const TOKEN = currentUser?.accessToken;
const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/";

export const userRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  headers: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` },
});
```

This is my API for the add order. When I try it on the postman, it works fine, but whenever I try it on a project, it gives me an error.

```
const router = require("express").Router();   
 router.post("/", verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
      const newOrder = new Order(req.body);
      try {
        const savedOrder = await newOrder.save();
        res.status(200).json(savedOrder);
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
      }
    });
```

This is the Order Schema.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        username: { type: String, required: true },
        email: { type: String },
        phone: { type: Number, required: true },
        products: [
            {
                productId: {
                    type: String
                },
                quantity: {
                    type: Number,
                    default: 1,
                },
            },
        ],
        amount: { type: Number, required: true },
        shippingPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
        address: { type: String, required: true },
        pincode: { type: Number, required: true },
        status: { type: String, default: "pending" },
        trackingId: { type: String },
        paymentMethod: { type: String, default: "Cash On Delivery" },
        reference: { type: String, unique: true },
    },

    { timestamps: true }

);
```

Comment: A "500 Internal Server Error" is a generic status code, that is not _supposed_ to give to much information away to any outside party; you need to go check the error log and find out what the actual _reason_ was first of all.

Comment: I have added the error log i am just not being able to understand whats causing the bad response.

Comment: That is just the log of the client-side part - it still tells us not much more, than _that_ a 500 occurred. You need to go check the error log of your _server-side_ code portion.

Comment: Did you tried to read the data? `data: {index: 0, code: 11000, keyPattern: {…}, keyValue: {…}}`

Comment: I am not getting any error in server's console. i was getting before but now its not comming.

Comment: yes i read the data. its data:
code: 11000
index: 0
keyPattern:
products.productId: 1
[[Prototype]]: Object
keyValue:
products.productId: "62b3968ad7cc2315f39450f3"
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[Prototype]]: Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an update.

I just deleted the table from mongoDB and then placed a new order and its fixed now